# Jquery creating a unique var for each element in an array based on element's name

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, arrays

I'm new to Jquery so hopefully this is possible.
I have a page with multiple textboxes. I'm trying to do the effect where the textbox will say for example `Email` then when you click on it, `Email` disappears and you can put in your own text. I already have that part of the code done.

Because I have multiple textboxes with different ID's and different starting values/placeholders, I'm trying to create a method which will, on the document readying, push every textbox on the page into an array, in the format of the textboxes id and it's value, separated by a character(I'm using :). I have this part done as well (supposedly)

I then need to loop through that array, and for each element in the array, separate the textbox Id and the textbox value. THEN I need to create a new `var` called the textbox's ID which contains the same textboxes value.

The end result should be multiple vars named after textboxes, each of which containing the equivalent textboxes value.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Create array to contain all textbox values on page load
       var textBoxValues = [];
$('[id^=mainArea_txt]').each(function(e){
    textBoxValues.push("#" + $(this).attr('id') + ":" + $(this).val());
    //0: #mainArea_txtEmail:Email
    //1: #mainArea_txtPassword:Password
    //2: #mainArea_txtConfirmPassword:Confirm Password
});
function createVarForeachElement(elem)
{
    var textboxId = elem.split(':')[0];
    var textboxValue = elem.split(':')[1];
}
textBoxValues.forEach(createVarForeachElement)
{
    //Create new var in the format " var [textboxId] = [textboxValue]   
};
```

});

Like I said I'm new to jquery so if someone could think of a better way to do this

Comment: This is mostly possible but what scope do you need your variables at? And what are you going to use the variables for? Generally you don't need to dynamically create variables, you would store things in an array or object, as you have started to do already.

Comment: This has been asked many, many times. See [*[javascript] how to dynamically create variables*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+dynamically+create+variables). It also has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Well, each variable will be storing the textboxes value on the page load, which is it's original value. When I implement the code to remove the placeholder in the textbox, I need to check first: "is the value currently in the textbox different than the original value". if it is, that means that the user has typed something in, and I don't want to do anything to the new value. if not, it means that the user didn't type anything, and i should restore the original placeholder.

Comment: @RobG Then I'm sure you won't have any trouble answering once more.

Comment: To compare the current value with the default, use `this.value == this.defaultValue`.

Comment: @Frayt the answer will probably be "look at the existing question". BTW the [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder) attribute could be useful for you

Comment: @RobG Thank you, I did not know about defaultValue. That's reduced this problem hugely.